# How to declare constexpr c-string member?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to declare constexpr c-string member ? Non-member constexpr c-string can be declared this way:

```
constexpr char id_[] = "aaa";
```

so I have though that I can declare it this way:

```
struct T
{
    const static constexpr char id_[] = "aaa";
};
```

but I get undefined reference error.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: Add `const constexpr char T::id_[];` outside the class to actually define it.

Comment: @NathanOliver `const constexpr` is redundant. Just `constexpr` will do, since it implies `const` :)

Comment: But const static members don't have to be defined outside. Why it doesn't work with constexpr ?

Comment: @Irbis They still have to be defined outside, but you can initialize them inside.  This has changed in C++17 with the introduction of `inline` for variables.  Since `constexpr` static members are implicitly inline you just need `static constexpr char id_[] = "aaa";` inside `T`.

Comment: You can use `const char T::id_[sizeof(T::id_)];` to define it outside.